# Why am i getting - component appears to be a function error - for stateless component in latest react using web dev server?

Tags: reactjs

Example:

```
const Loading = () => (
<div className="x">
  <i className="loading" />
</div>
)
```

This returns horrible red console warnings in chrome.

Why should I make it a class? It had no need to be? This is since latest upgrade to react 16.2

Comment: Please show us the code you're using to render the `Loading` component

Comment: Can you add the component where you render the Loading component. It will be helpful to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the cause. I had upgraded react and react dom but not react-hot-reloader. 
I was using react-hot-loader: 4.2.0

Strange bug.

Upgraded now to 4.12.18, and this is resolved.

Unrelated but also necessary for testing:
Also noted enzyme tests were failing too after upgrade and enzyme-adaptor-16 also needed updating.